# How to exit a shell script if targeted file doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exit

Given the script below, I would like to avoid the execution of the pipeline if a file does not exist.

How may I exit the script straight away if the text file is not found?

```bash
ls */*.txt | grep ab1 | awk '{print $1, $1}' | sed "s/\"/\"\"/g" | xargs -L1 mv
```

Comment: You probably want `rename` for this.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can check for file existence with something like:

```
if [[ -f x.txt ]] ; then
    echo file exists.
fi
```

To exit if it *doesn't,* something like this would suffice:

```
if [[ ! -f x.txt ]] ; then
    echo 'File "x.txt" is not there, aborting.'
    exit
fi
```

The `-f <file>` is only *one* of the many conditional expressions you can use. If you look at the `bash` man-page under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`, you'll see a whole host of them.

---

If (as stated in a question update) you wish to check if a wildcard results in files, you can simply expand it, throwing away the errors. If there are none, you'll end up with an empty string which can be detected with `-z`:

```
if [[ -z "$(ls -1 */*.txt 2>/dev/null | grep ab1)" ]] ; then
    echo 'There are no "*/*.txt" files.'
    exit
fi
```

Note that I've used `-1` to force one file per line even though Linux `ls` does that by default if the output device is not a terminal (from memory). That's just in case you try this on a machine that *doesn't* force one per line in that case.

---

Keep in mind however that, if you have spaces in your filenames, using `ls` and then `awk` to extract column 1 is not going to work too well. For example, the file `abc ab1.txt` will result in the extraction of only the `abc` bit.

Using `find` with `-print0`, combined with `xargs` with `-0` is the usual way to properly process files which may have "special" characters in them. There are many other options you can give to `find` to ensure only the files required are processed, such as `-maxdepth` to limit how far down the directory tree you go, and `-name` to properly filter file names.

However, if you *know* that you will never have these types of files, it's probably okay to use the `ls` solution, just make sure you're comfortable with its shortcomings.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, 

Sorry i have miss out the * sign, suppose to be [ls * / *.txt].

Comment: @amine, no probs, added an addendum to take care of that.

Comment: Work perfectly. Thanks paxdiablo. =)

Answer (score 23):

### Use `test`

A quick and short way of testing for existence:

```
test -e $FILENAME || exit
```

You can chain it by doing:

```
test -e $FILENAME && something | something-else
```

In which case `something` and `something-else` will only execute if the file exists.

For example:

```
➤ test -e ~/.bashrc && echo True || echo False
True
➤ test -e ./exists-not && echo True || echo False
False
```

*Aside:* Note that `[` is an alias for `test`. The semantics of `[[` are defined by bash and can be found [on the bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

### However...

...you are probably better off using `find` to get your files:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 2 -name "*ab1*.txt" -exec do-something-to-filename '{}' \;
```

As the output of `ls` can not be reliably parsed. This will also only execute the command `do-something-to-filename` if the filename exist, which is what I think you are trying to do.

`{}` will be replaced by the filename for each invocation of `do-something-to-filename`.

Comment: Hi brice, thanks for the alternative, "test" command is fast and simple. But what can i do if do not know the full filename and i just know the file is in .txt format. Wondering whether test command has any function to do it?

Comment: test command doesn't and your best bet is definitely using `find`. You can use find inside of test to have everything on one line though: `test -n "$(find ./ -maxdepth 2 -name "*er*.py")" && do-stuff || handle-failure`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and this worked for me

```
test -s <<your file path>> && exit 0 || <<things to do when file NOT exists>>
```

Note that i am actually exiting when the file is not present

Answer (score -1):

`find ... -exec ...` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` is generally fine, but you can do it directly with a glob using bash's `nullglob` option:

```
bash-3.2$ echo *foo
*foo
bash-3.2$ shopt -s nullglob
bash-3.2$ echo *foo

bash-3.2$
```

Depending on the rest of your script, you may or may not want to re-unset that with `shopt -u nullglob`.